# Mongoose DocumentDB connection fails through SSH tunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect to AWS DocumentDB with Node.js/Typescript and Mongoose. I have an EC2 instance setup as SSL tunnel, which works great. I can connect to DocumentDB locally with Studio3T and mongo-cli.
This command works `mongo --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --ssl --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username <username> --password <password>`

But if I try to connect to the same database with Mongoose, it fails. This is my code and the error:

```js
const options = {
  dbName: "prodDB",
  user: connectionData.username,
  pass: connectionData.password,
  tls: true,
  tlsCAFile: "../rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
  tlsAllowInvalidHostNames: true,
};
try {
  await connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", options);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

```bash
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect EHOSTUNREACH imagine-ip-address-here:27017
reason: TopologyDescription {
  type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
  servers: Map(1) {
    'censored:27017' => [ServerDescription]
  },
  stale: false,
  compatible: true,
  heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
  localThresholdMS: 15,
  setName: 'rs0',
  commonWireVersion: 7,
  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
}
```

At this point, I have tried pretty much any possible config in Mongoose and I am getting desperate. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Since you censored an IP address and I assume you do know that 127.0.0.1 or ::1 are loopback addresses and don't need censoring, it makes me think that somehow the connection was attempted to some server and not `localhost` as you specified. Either the `connect` function which you didn't show somehow doesn't respect the Mongo URI or you have a line in your `/etc/hosts` that resolves `localhost` to something _other_ than a loopback address...

Comment: The connect function is the mongoose default connect function. The IP seems to be the address of the documentdb cluster

Comment: Yep, seems like Mongoose is doing something wrong in the newest version. Downgrading fixed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with mongoose versions >= 6.
Downgrading Mongoose to version 5.13.8 works without a problem.
Mongoose devs are apparently aware of this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11105

Comment: Following this, it works fine in versions >= 6. In that same github issue, the author found a solution to the problem by adding a couple of extra parameters to the tunnel connection and adding "directConnection: true" to your connection options. Worked for me.

Comment: Just adding, I had to follow some of the settings in the git issue that @WuelberCastillo mentioned to get this working with the MongoDB client, not  using Mongoose.